# Passing method to all android activities - classes

Tags: java, android

I have this method defined in MainActivity class:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context c) {
      ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo netInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
}
```

I would like to use it in all other activities/classes of my application. How can i do that? (I know, this is a main Java feature, but i can't get out of it). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a class called BaseActivity extends Activity(Don't declare in manifest), and all your activities should extend this BaseActivty. All the common functions shall be in this BaseActivty. Thus all your activities will have the functions in BaseActivity.

Comment: This seems to be the best and easier way! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a static method, you can access it as

`MainActivity.isOnline(context)`

However as a general rule, you can create a new Utils.java class and have all your common static methods defined there.

`Utils.isOnline(context)`

Comment: You can create it in the same package. com.your.package.Utils.java